# Solve the DFE $xy'^3 - 2yy'^2 - 16x^2 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've started like this:

From $xy'^3 - 2yy'^2 - 16x^2 = 0$, we find that $$y = -8x^2/p^2 + 1/2 \cdot xp,$$ with $p = y' = dy/dx$.

Taking the derivative yields $$p = -16x/p^2 + 16 x^2p'/p^3 + 1/2p + 1/2 \cdot xp'$$ And working out the denominator gives us $$p^4 = -32xp + 32x^2 p' + xp^2p'.$$
At this point, I don't know how to go on. I tried separating the terms containing $p$ and $p'$, but it didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Maple solves this equation!

Comment: What is a DFE? If you're going to use abbreviations that you invented yourself, you probably need to define them for us.

Answer (score 5):

We are given

$$\tag 1 xy'^3 - 2yy'^2 - 16x^2 = 0$$

We will rewrite $(1)$ using $p = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$ as

$$\tag 2 x p^3 - 2 y p^2 - 16 x^2 = 0$$

Isolating $y$ in $(2)$, we have

$$\tag 3 y = \dfrac{1}{2}( x p - 16 x^2 p^{-2})$$

Differentiating $(3$), we have

$$\tag 4 y ' = p = \dfrac{1}{2}(p + x p' - 32~ x~ p^{-2} + 32 ~x^2~ p^{-3}p')$$

Factoring $(4)$, we have

$$\tag 5 \dfrac{(32 x + p^3)(p - x p')}{2 p^3} = 0$$

From $(5)$, we solve for the two expressions

$$p^3 + 32 x = 0 \\ p - x p' = 0$$

I will assume you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! One question though: in (4); why is $y' = 0$?

Comment: One should not ignore the envelope $$y=-\frac12(x(32x)^{1/3}+16x^2(32x)^{-2/3})$$ of the solution family $$y=\frac12(Cx^2-16C^{-2}).$$ Piecewise combinations of these functions are also solutions.

Comment: @LutzL: Good point - I didn't say that at first, but then changed my answer to ignore it - but I will change it back to my original solution. Thanks

Comment: I think you meant $y' = p$ instead of $y' = \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}x}$ in line 4.

Comment: @MichaelLee: You are correct - typos! Corrected - thanks!

Comment: @LutzL : When I put your solution back into $xy'^3 - 2yy'^2 - 16x^2 = 0$ it doesn't agree. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Moo: It seems that you solved  $xy'^3 - 2yy'^2  = 0$ but not $xy'^3 - 2yy'^2 - 16x^2 = 0$ Am I mistaken ?

Comment: @JJacquelin You would have to be a bit more specific. The family has $y'=Cx$ and when you insert that you get an identity. The other curve is the envelope with points of tangency at $\pm x_{tan}$ for $C^3=-32/x_{tan}^2$. As to the second comment, please explain as the coefficient $16$ is plainly visible in all the transformations.

Comment: @LutzL: If I insert $y'=Cx$ in $xy'^3 - 2yy'^2 - 16x^2 = 0$, I obtain $-16x^2=0$ which is false.

Comment: Note, it isn't a concern for me. I just wanted to draw attention that one have to put any proposed solution $y(x)$ into the ODE $xy'^3 - 2yy'^2 - 16x^2 = 0$ and check if it agrees.

Comment: That is a strange result. I get $C^3x^4-2C^2x^2y-16x^2=0$ which can be transformed back to $y=\frac{C^3x^2-16}{2C^2}$ which is identical to the solution.

Comment: @JJacquelin: The $16x^2$ term is included in the solution as shown in $(4)$ with the two derivative terms that make it a $32$.

Comment: OK. Now I agree : $y(x)=\frac{C^3x^2-16}{2c^2}$  is a family of solutions, to be completed with  $y=-\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}}x^{4/3}$ . Thank you to LutzL and Moo for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

$$p^4 = -32xp + 32x^2 p' + xp^2p'.$$
$$(32x^2 + xp^2)p'=p^4 +32xp  .$$
This is an generalized Abel's equation of the second kind :
$$y'\sum_{j=0}^{2}g_j(x)y^j=\sum_{j=0}^{4}f_j(x)y^j$$
where $g_0(x)=32x^2 \:;\:g_2(x)=x \:;\: f_1(x)=32x \:;\: f_4(x)=1 \:;\:g_1(x)=f_0(x)=f_2(x)=f_3(x)=0  .$

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Abel_differential_equation

The majority of this kind of equations are not solvable on a closed form. Nevertheless, some particular solutions can sometimes be found. Knowing a boundary condition can eventually help.

In the case of the original equation :
$$xy'^3 - 2yy'^2 - 16x^2 = 0$$
looking for a particular solution on the form $y_p(x)=ax^p$ leads to :
$$y_p=-\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}}x^{4/3}$$

Comment: Notice that you can cancel the factor $32x+p^3$ in the second equation, as long as it is not zero. Then you are back to the solutions in the answer of Moo. -- By chance the monomial family indeed gives a solution which is the envelope of the parabolic solutions.

Comment: @JJacquelin: Very nice observations regarding that this is a generalized Abel equation - I didn't even see that. (+1).